# Syntax error in UPDATE statement vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

i'm having trouble in my code. i just couldn't find the solution. When i run my program it always gives me an error

> syntax error in UPDATE statement

here's the code.

```
    Try
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BC_Inventory SET [Price]='" + PriceU.Text + "',[Addition]='" + AddU.Text + "'," + _
        "[Date_Updated]='" + DateU.Text + "',[Time_Updated]='" + TimeU.Text + "',[Updated_By]='" + UpdatedBy.Text + "'," + _
        "WHERE [Item]='" + com_ItemU.Text + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    MsgBox("Inventory updated!")
```

Comment: prepare to hear about sql injection and sql parameters.

Comment: "update by 'whoever', where" gives clearly syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added extra `","` after `[Updated_By]` (`[Updated_By]='" + UpdatedBy.Text + "',"` <- extra `","`) which is giving Syntax error

Comment: Solved. I didn't see that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BC_Inventory SET [Price]='" + PriceU.Text + "',[Addition]='" + AddU.Text + "'," + _
    "[Date_Updated]='" + DateU.Text + "',[Time_Updated]='" + TimeU.Text + "',[Updated_By]='" + UpdatedBy.Text + "' " + _
    "WHERE [Item]='" + com_ItemU.Text + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

*Print* your query out somehow before executing it, that's standard debugging 101.

That tends to solve 97.2% <sup>(a)</sup> of *all* SQL statement problems.

By that, I mean something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "some hideously long and complex statement"
MessageBox (cmd.CommandText) ' Add this debug line temporarily'
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In this particular case, it's the comma before the `where` clause.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I just pulled this figure out of the ether. *Actual* results may vary, but I bet it'll fix more problems than *not* doing it :-)

Comment: If anything, your figure is too low.